# How do I make my code loop the function fight()

Tags: python

```
import random
user = input("You reconize this creture. The feared BaLaKe. Its weakness is 'rock', 'paper',''scissors' Are you willing to challenge him in a battle of Rock Paper Scissors? (ENTER)" )
print("ROARRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR!!!!!")
```

> > Below is the function I want to loop when userhealth and dragonhealth <= 0. I want it to keep asking for input for rock, paper, or scissors and go through the conditions.

```
def fight(userhealth,dragonhealth):
 dragon = random.choice(["r","p","s"])
 user=input("Rock(r), Paper(p) or Scissors(s): ").lower()
 print(dragon)
 if user==dragon:
     print("You both missed your attacks. Bruh ;-;")
 elif is_win(user,dragon):

        dragonhealth-=20 
        print("You hit BaLaKe! 20 DMG Done!!! :) ") 
        print("Your health: "+str(userhealth )+" HP")
        print("BaLaKe\'s health: "+str(dragonhealth )+" HP") 
        
     else: 
      print("Ow! You got hit by BaLake. -20 HP :( ")     
      userhealth-=20 
      print("Your health: "+str(userhealth )+" HP")
      print("BaLaKe\'s health: "+str(dragonhealth )+" HP")
    
    def is_win(player,opponent):
        if (player=="r" and opponent=="s") or (player=="s" and opponent=="p") or (player=="p" and opponent=="r"):
         return True
    
    
    fight(100,100)
```

Comment: Have you tried using a while construct?

Comment: Is while construct a while loop?

Comment: Yes, in python the `while` keyword is used for looping. Have you come across this before?

Comment: Yup I have. But what should the condition be tho?
I can probably write this:
while ... :
fight(100,100)?

Comment: I sounds like you need the `while` inside the `fight()` function. Maybe `while userhealth > 0 and dragonhealth > 0:` as the first line.

Comment: I tried it. When I write this outside the function. It said it said dragonhealth and userhealth is not defined. But when I write it I write it in the function, nothing happens.

Comment: I can see two answers currently. One has the `while` inside the function, and the other has it outside. Both seem to be quite reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use While loop for repeating the game util someone gets 0 HP.
2. I created a function to terminate the game when someone is at 0 HP. See it

   enter code here

```py
import random

user_health = 100  # used underscore snake case love:)
dragon_health = 100  # I initialized both variables outside


def fight(user_health, dragon_health):  # according to PEP8 I guess. we shouldn't use shadow names. Still,not a big deal
    dragon = random.choice(["r", "p", "s"])
    user = input("Rock(r), Paper(p) or Scissors(s): ").lower()
    print(dragon)

    if user == dragon:
        print("You both missed your attacks. Bruh ;-;")
        return user_health, dragon_health
    elif is_win(user, dragon):

        dragon_health -= 20
        print("You hit BaLaKe! 20 DMG Done!!! :) ")  #
        print("Your health: " + str(user_health) + " HP")
        print("BaLaKe\'s health: " + str(dragon_health) + " HP")
        return user_health, dragon_health

    else:
        print("Ow! You got hit by BaLake. -20 HP :( ")
        user_health -= 20
        print("Your health: " + str(user_health) + " HP")
        print("BaLaKe\'s health: " + str(dragon_health) + " HP")
        return user_health, dragon_health


def is_win(player, opponent):
    if (player == "r" and opponent == "s") or (player == "s" and opponent == "p") or (
            player == "p" and opponent == "r"):
        return True


# this function terminates game when someone is at 0 HP and prints output
def game_terminator(user_health, dragon_health):  # I continued with the shadow names to avoid confusion
    if user_health == 0:
        print("Dragon killed you!")
        return False
    elif dragon_health == 0:
        print("Thrashed dragon to dealth! YOU WON!")  # Nerd outputs :)
        return False
    else:
        return True


game_is_on = True
# Use while loop for game to run until someone gets 0 HP
while game_is_on:  # game_is_on is a boolean variable
    user_health, dragon_health = fight(user_health, dragon_health)
    game_is_on = game_terminator(user_health, dragon_health)

  # Thank Me :)
```

Comment: Also, whats this code for ' user_health, dragon_health = fight(user_health, dragon_health)'.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want this ?

```
import random
user = input("You recognize this creture. The feared BaLaKe. Its weakness is 'rock', 'paper',''scissors' Are you willing to challenge him in a battle of Rock Paper Scissors? (ENTER)" )
print("ROARRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR!!!!!")
def fight(userhealth,dragonhealth):

  while(userhealth>0 and dragonhealth>0):

    dragon = random.choice(["r","p","s"])
    user=input("Rock(r), Paper(p) or Scissors(s): ").lower()
    print(dragon)
    if user==dragon:
        print("You both missed your attacks. Bruh ;-;")
    elif is_win(user,dragon):

            dragonhealth-=20 
            print("You hit BaLaKe! 20 DMG Done!!! :) ") 
            print("Your health: "+str(userhealth )+" HP")
            print("BaLaKe\'s health: "+str(dragonhealth )+" HP") 
            
    else: 
        print("Ow! You got hit by BaLake. -20 HP :( ")     
        userhealth-=20 
        print("Your health: "+str(userhealth )+" HP")
        print("BaLaKe\'s health: "+str(dragonhealth )+" HP")
        
    def is_win(player,opponent):
        if (player=="r" and opponent=="s") or (player=="s" and opponent=="p") or (player=="p" and opponent=="r"):
            return True


fight(100,100)
```

Comment: It says "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'is_win' referenced before assignment" when I put in my input of rock paper and scissors

Comment: Check spaces before def is_win(... Maybe copy-paste adds some extra spaces

Comment: Works fine for me after I indented the `while`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
import random

user = input("You reconize this creture. The feared BaLaKe. Its weakness is 'rock', 'paper',''scissors' Are you willing to challenge him in a battle of Rock Paper Scissors? (ENTER)" )
print("ROARRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR!!!!!")
dragonhealth = 100
userhealth = 100

def fight(userhealth,dragonhealth,choice):
    dragon = random.choice(["r","p","s"])
    print(dragon)
    if choice==dragon:
        print("You both missed your attacks. Bruh ;-;")

    elif is_win(choice,dragon):
        dragonhealth-=20 
        print("You hit BaLaKe! 20 DMG Done!!! :) ") 
        print("Your health: "+str(userhealth )+" HP")
        print("BaLaKe\'s health: "+str(dragonhealth )+" HP") 
        
    else: 
        print("Ow! You got hit by BaLake. -20 HP :( ")     
        userhealth-=20 
        print("Your health: "+str(userhealth )+" HP")
        print("BaLaKe\'s health: "+str(dragonhealth )+" HP")
    return userhealth,dragonhealth
        
def is_win(player,opponent):
    if (player=="r" and opponent=="s") or (player=="s" and opponent=="p") or (player=="p" and opponent=="r"):
        return True

while (userhealth>0 or dragonhealth>0):
    choice=input("Rock(r), Paper(p) or Scissors(s): ").lower()
    userhealth,dragonhealth = fight(userhealth,dragonhealth,choice)

if userhealth>0:
    print("You won! ")
elif dragonhealth>0:
    print("You lost! ")
```

Explanation: Sets the original healths at the start. Sets up a while loop to check if either of them have less than 0 health. Subtracts and updates the health when you lose/win. Declares a winner at the end!